# newcommand for ket-bra

Tags: macros

How can create a `\newcommand` that be able generate:

```
|\phi\rangle\langle \psi|
```

However `\ket{\phi}\bra{\psi}` does that but we think that the distance between `ket` and `bra` in `|\phi\rangle\langle \psi|` is shorter than that of `\ket{\phi}\bra{\psi}`.

Comment: `\op{\phi}{\psi}` from the `physics` package does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `braket` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

$\braket{\varphi|\psi}$

$\bra{\varphi}$

$\ket{\psi}$

$\ket{\varphi}\bra{\psi}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The spacing for the ketbra is too large.

Comment: @orlp I believe this is a precise choice by the author of `braket`. Nothing prevents you from defining `\newcommand{\ketbra}[2]{\mathinner{|{#1}\rangle\,\langle{#2}|}}` that would use just one thin space in the middle instead of two.

Answer (score 2):

try the command `\ketbra{\phi}{\psi}`, this should minimize the distance between the ket and the bra.

[image: command \ketbra{\phi}{\psi}]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add a screenshot of your result? (And no, I did not downvote!)

Comment: This is actually the correct answer - use `\ketbra` from the `physics` package.

Comment: @AntiEarth The `physics` package has several drawbacks.